# Cross compilation openCV application

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, arm

Hi guys I am doing an application in c++ for ARM. I have a application prototype which I compiled with cross compilation and it works very nice in the ARM. What I did was this:

First I got the .o file like this

```
arm-linux-g++ -c PrototipoTRU.cpp
```

Then I got the .exe like this (My application use thread)

```
arm-linux-g++ PrototipoTRU.o -o tru2 -pthread
```

and everything works perfect.

My problem is when I tried to compile an .cpp file which use OpenCV. I tried that:

First I tried to got the .o:

```
 arm-linux-g++ -c camera.cpp
```

That does not work, I got this output:

```
IPCamera.cpp:5:30: error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
IPCamera.cpp:6:39: error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
IPCamera.cpp:7:39: error: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp: No such file or directory
IPCamera.cpp:11:22: error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
IPCamera.cpp:16: error: 'cv' is not a namespace-name
IPCamera.cpp:16: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
IPCamera.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
IPCamera.cpp:46: error: 'cv' has not been declared
IPCamera.cpp:46: error: expected ';' before 'cap'
IPCamera.cpp:52: error: 'Display' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:52: error: 'disp' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:52: error: 'XOpenDisplay' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:53: error: 'Screen' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:53: error: 'scrn' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:53: error: 'DefaultScreenOfDisplay' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:63: error: 'cv' has not been declared
IPCamera.cpp:63: error: expected ';' before 'frame'
IPCamera.cpp:66: error: 'cv' has not been declared
IPCamera.cpp:66: error: 'CV_WINDOW_NORMAL' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:68: error: 'cvMoveWindow' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:73: error: 'CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:73: error: 'CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:73: error: 'cvSetWindowProperty' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:79: error: 'cap' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:82: error: 'frame' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:89: error: 'cv' has not been declared
IPCamera.cpp:92: error: 'cv' has not been declared
```

So it seem that there is some problem with the link, however if do this:

```
 g++ -c IPCamera.cpp
```

I got the .o file, but obviously when I get the .exe it does not work in the ARM . What I do not undestand is why if I compile an application without opencv, like the first example, the arm-linux-g++ works propertly and when I try to compile the openCV application no.

I tried to compiler also like this:

```
 arm-linux-g++ -c IPCamera.cpp `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags`
```

but is the same result, however if I do this:

```
 g++ -c IPCamera.cpp `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags`
```

It works. So I guess that is a path problem but I do not have idea how I can solved it.

Someone can help me??

Thank you guys

Hi dennisfen this is the content of mi file:

```
 set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
 set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
 set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

 set(GCC_COMPILER_VERSION "4.6" CACHE STRING "GCC Compiler version")

 set(FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX "")

 if (NOT SOFTFP)
   set(FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX "hf")
 endif()

 set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    arm-linux- 
 gnueabi${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-gcc-${GCC_COMPILER_VERSION})
 set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  arm-linux-
 gnueabi${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-g++-${GCC_COMPILER_VERSION})
 set(ARM_LINUX_SYSROOT /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX} CACHE PATH "ARM cross 
 compilation system root")

 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS           ""                    CACHE STRING "c++ flags")
 set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS             ""                    CACHE STRING "c flags")
 set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS ""                    CACHE STRING "shared linker flags")
 set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS ""                    CACHE STRING "module linker flags")
 set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS    "-Wl,-z,nocopyreloc"  CACHE STRING "executable linker 
 flags")

 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack 
 -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi")
 set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS   "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack 
 -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi")

 set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-
 sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}")
 set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-
 sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now ${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
 set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS    "-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-
 sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to set include path to your cross OpenCV installation:

```
arm-linux-g++ -I/path/to/opencv/include IPCamera.cpp -o tru2
```

When you call pkg-config it reports settings for you host system not for your arm cross toolchain.

Comment: Hi dennis thank you for your answer, I do not have to much idea, so you mean something like this? arm-linux-g++ -I/usr/include/opencv IPCamera.cpp -o tru2

Comment: @user3536692, you should use path to cross-compiled installation of opencv for you target platform (arm in your case). It should be somewhere in /opt or in your home dir if you built it from sources or in /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/ (or similar) if you installed it from your distro repo.

Comment: Hi dennisfen thenk you for your answer and patient. Ok I hope I undestand, I have the cross-compiled intallation in this path: /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/include, but I got this toolchain from the ARM siteweb, so Should I download an special opencv toolchains??

Comment: @user3536692 You need to download opencv sources, compile it with your arm toolchain (/opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnuea‌​bi/) and install somewhere (f.e., /opt/freescale/opencv). Then compile your app with headers from /opt/freescale/opencv/include and link to libs from /opt/freescale/opencv/lib.

Comment: Hi dennisfen, so I download opencv source from here "git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git", and now for compile with my toolchain shall I add to the arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake something like this: "set(COMPILER_ROOT /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnue‌​a‌​bi/)" for indicate compile with my toolchain?? and then install. Is that right?? I cannot undestand how this is so complicate for me man, I am from Spain man if I get to do that I will send you a Pata negra I promise

Comment: @user3536692 try `set(COMPILER_ROOT /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi)`

Comment: I edited your answer but I do not know why someone deleted it,

Comment: So I edited my question, please let me know if you know what I have to change. Thank you so much for your patient

Comment: @user3536692 try to change block of lines in your config starting with:
`set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabi${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-gcc-${GCC_COMPILER_VERSION})`
to this:
` set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-gcc-${GCC_COMPILER_VERSION})
 set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-g++-${GCC_COMPILER_VERSION})
 set(ARM_LINUX_SYSROOT /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnuea‌​bi${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX} CACHE PATH "ARM cross compilation system root")`

Comment: Hi dennisfen I get this output: -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working CXX compiler: arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.7
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.7" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.7 -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (MESSAGE):

Comment: @user3536692 change this `set(GCC_COMPILER_VERSION "4.6" CACHE STRING "GCC Compiler version")` to `set(GCC_COMPILER_VERSION "4.4.4" CACHE STRING "GCC Compiler version")` in your cmake settings file

Comment: Hi dennisfen finally I got make de cmake with this:  set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++) 
set(ARM_LINUX_SYSROOT /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnuea‌​‌​bi/bin${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX} CACHE PATH "ARM cross compilation system root")

Comment: @user3536692 any success yet?

Answer (score 0):

As @dennisfen suggest you may need to set include path as well as the library path to your cross OpenCV with the libraries you are using as follows:

```
arm-linux-g++ -I/path/to/opencv/include -L/path/to/library IPCamera.cpp -o tru2 -lopencv_core -pthread
```

Comment: Hi Nisarg thank you for your answer, one thing, when I create a project in eclipse i have to add the path libraries, in GCC C++ Compiler->Includes->paths(-l) I write /usr/include/opencv2, and in GCC C++ linker->Libraries(-l) I write opencv_core, pthread, opencv_imgproc, opencv_highgui, opencv_ml. In GCC C++ Linker->Libraries(-L) I write /usr/lib, and everything is working. Then what I tried like you told me was this: arm-linux-g++ -I/usr/include/opencv2 -L/usr/lib IPCamera.cpp -o tru2 -lopencv_core -pthread -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml. And I get the same error.

Comment: So please I need some help because I do know what I am doing wrong.