# Cross compile Opencv for ARM

Tags: c++, opencv, arm

Hi guys I am trying to cross-compile an application which use c++ with opencv for an ARM.

I got the toolchain from the ARM site web, and it works propertly for applications without opencv libraries.

I was reading and asking and I find out that I have to download the opencv sources, then compile it with my toolchain and install somewhere, and then I could compile my app.

The thing is that I get the opencv source from here "git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git" Once the download is finish I can see this file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(GCC_COMPILER_VERSION "4.6" CACHE STRING "GCC Compiler version")

set(FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX "")

if (NOT SOFTFP)
   set(FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX "hf")
endif()

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    arm-linux-
gnueabi${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-gcc-${GCC_COMPILER_VERSION})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  arm-linux-
gnueabi${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-g++-${GCC_COMPILER_VERSION})
set(ARM_LINUX_SYSROOT /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX} CACHE PATH "ARM cross 
compilation system root")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS           ""                    CACHE STRING "c++ flags")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS             ""                    CACHE STRING "c flags")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS ""                    CACHE STRING "shared linker flags")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS ""                    CACHE STRING "module linker flags")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS    "-Wl,-z,nocopyreloc"  CACHE STRING "executable linker 
flags")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack 
-fsigned-char -Wno-psabi")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS   "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack 
-fsigned-char -Wno-psabi")

set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now ${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS    "-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")

 if(USE_NEON)
   message(WARNING "You use obsolete variable USE_NEON to enable NEON instruction set. 
 Use -DENABLE_NEON=ON instead." )
   set(ENABLE_NEON TRUE)
 elseif(USE_VFPV3)
   message(WARNING "You use obsolete variable USE_VFPV3 to enable VFPV3 instruction 
 set. Use -DENABLE_VFPV3=ON instead." )
   set(ENABLE_VFPV3 TRUE)
 endif()

 set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH} ${ARM_LINUX_SYSROOT})

 if(EXISTS ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR})
     set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH} ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR})
 endif()

 set( CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH TRUE CACHE BOOL "If set, runtime paths are not added when  
 using      shared libraries." )
 set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
 set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
 set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM ONLY)
```

I red that I should change this file for indicate the toolchain which I have already in my computer, I have it here:

```
 /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi
```

and then do somenthing like this:

```
 cmake -DSOFTFP=ON  -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../opencv/platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake ../opencv
```

That is the PATH in which I have the above file.

My question is if this is correct, and what should I change in the above file for indicate it my toolchain for compile??

Thank you guys

Comment: note that opencv has already been compiled for ARM; you can find some mirrors for example here: http://download.opensuse.org/ports/armv7hl/distribution/13.1/repo/oss/suse/armv7hl/

Comment: sorry chris but I dont know what you mean?

Comment: if you are on a linux platform on ARM; you might not need to compile opencv; since it is already available on some repositories... on opensuse13.1 for example as in my comment above.

Comment: I have an application in c++ which use opencv, what I want is get an .exe for execute in my ARM. For get that .exe I need to compile my application with toolchain. So How you mean I can get the .exe?

Comment: your question has been marked a duplicate; start looking at the duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081413/cross-compilation-opencv-application

Comment: I am just trying to make the answer in other way for get different answer because I cannot get the solution. It seem that is working because you give me other answer which I am trying to undestand.